# Multi threading in hp load runner

Tags: c, multithreading, loadrunner

I want to do multi threading at HP load runner VUGEN, the problem is there is no support for pthread as well as windows thread. How can i implement this?
VUGEN has been implemented by c only, but it does not support all th ec methods. How can i write a header file thus I can acess multi threading.

If you people thinks that it's a bad question, still please reply rather that giving -1.

Comment: You can use any C library you want. Just add whatever files you use to the Extra Files of the script.

Comment: i have tried to use windows.h, to use windows thread,but that header is not supported by lr.

Answer (score -1):

Multithreading can be implemented through Controller/PC only.

You need to setup number of Vusers in Controller/Performance Center in order to do multithreading.